# Read RGB values from PNG in C++

Tags: c++, rgb, fread

Basically, what I am trying to is learn how to open an image manually WITHOUT LIBRARIES and see the RGB contents.

I want to do this so I can calculate the Hue and Saturation of the RGB to write back a 2D array image.

So far I have got this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>      /* printf */
#include <math.h>       /* acos */
#include <fstream>      /* for file I/O */

using namespace std;

int main() {
        FILE* fp = NULL;
        fp = fopen("soccerball.png", "rb");
        cout << "done" << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

I know it is not much, as I'm used to Python more. But I honestly don't know where to start. And there are literally no examples of this it seems on the internet.

So I read an image. Now I want something like:

> img[Height][width]

so I can get

> img_r[h][w], img_g[h][w], img_b[h][w]

So I can use those values to calculate a Hue 2d array in same format.

> img_hue[h][w]

Thanks

Comment: You do know that BMP is far, far, far simpler to read than PNG without libraries?

Comment: @AndreasRejbrand I'd second that. BMP is a great place to start with working with raw image data. Then GIF to get a feel for LZW, then PNG. JPEG is not going to happen without some serious effort, it's by far the most punishing.

Comment: Can I easily convert BMP back to PNG after?

Comment: With a conversion tool, sure. Remember, PNG is typically compressed, and compression is very, very non-trivial to implement.

Comment: Ok, I just don't know where to start. For instance, how do I get the height and width of the image? or is it easier to read pixel by pixel to get the RGB?

Comment: You'll have to look up the file format specification for the particular format you're using. The size is probably in the header somewhere.

Comment: why don't you want to use a library? libpng is the definitive one.

Comment: Width and height of what, are you still talking about PNG or has this conversation switched to BMP?

Comment: Either, I just want to convert RGB to Hue and Saturation but I don't even know how to get the RGB values of the pixels.

Comment: [BMP file structure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BMP_file_format#File_structure)

Answer (score 1):

You can't easily open a PNG file without libraries.

Here is sample of opening a PNG WITH a library... and it's already a lot of code
http://zarb.org/~gc/html/libpng.html

The thing is that PNG is compressed format. There's a lot of "mathemagics" happening to compress the RGB values into the special format.

A .BMP (Windows bitmap for example) is a very easy way for you to start parsing manually, if you are doing this for training, but other formats you need a library.

Of couse, you CAN do everything from scratch... but will take a while and by the question you did, you are a little far from it.

Comment: This is nice and all, and I found this example. But for a beginner in C++. This is a little mind blowing

Comment: cool! :-) I would recommend you to learn reading and writing a ".BMP" first. They are very easy to do manually. Once you are good with this... learn how to use a lib_png.

Comment: I get this error when running that: Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_png_create_info_struct", referenced from:
      _main in rgb2hsv-0f0846.o
  "_png_create_read_struct", referenced from:
      _main in rgb2hsv-0f0846.o
  "_png_init_io", referenced from:
      _main in rgb2hsv-0f0846.o

Comment: sorry, this is not a specific problem of lib_png, but you need firstly study the basics of C/C++ compile + link process. In this case you are including the header files from lib_png but not linking against the library. google for "how to link libraries in c/c++" or something similiar first.

Comment: oh i tried running from the terminal on a mac and I guess I misunderstood how to link. sorry

Answer (score 0):

The file lodePNG by Lode Vandevenne

https://github.com/MalcolmMcLean/babyxrc/blob/master/src/lodepng.c

is an example of a PNG parser written from the ground up.

You can write your own parser, given the file format, but it's a bit involved. As a first shot, see if you can open a binary and detect whether it is or is not a PNG.